# Find zero points with recursion

Tags: java, math, recursion, binary-search

I want to find the zero points of a sine function. The parameter is a interval [a,b]. I have to it similar to binary search.

*Implement a function that searches for null points in the sinus function in a interval between a and b. The search-interval[lower limit, upper limit] should be halved until lower limit and upper limit are less then 0.0001 away from each other.*

Here is my code:

```
public class Aufg3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(zeropoint(5,8));
    }

    private static double zeropoint(double a, double b){
        double middle = (a + b)/2;

        if(Math.sin(middle) < 0){
            return zeropoint(a,middle);
        }else if(Math.sin(middle) > 0){
            return zeropoint(middle,b);
        }else{
            return middle;
        }       
    }
}
```

It gives me a lot of errors at the line with *return zeropoint(middle,b);*

In a first step I want to find just the first zero point in the interval.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you should use the same name for all uses of the variable currently named alternately `middle` and `mitte`?

Comment: Also, you are currently calling `Math.sin` twice. This is an expensive function and it would be good style to factor the calls into one.

Comment: also, you will never get the Math.sin() == 0. It's double and double nearly never can be compared to 0. Compare it like abs(Math.sin(mitte)) < 0.0001

Comment: @Vladimir, well the exercise says *until lower limit and upper limit are less then 0.0001 away from each other* so I'd terminate the recursion when `b-a < 0.0001`. (See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086385/find-zero-points-with-recursion/4086458#4086458).)

Comment: Yeah, what Vladimir said. If b-a < 0.0001 return middle, otherwise use a single if / else to decide which side to recurse into. Assume you'll never get an exact answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find null points of sinus function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085115/find-null-points-of-sinus-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fundamental problems that everybody has overlooked:

- we don't always want to return a result (imagine finding the zero points of the sine function between pi/4 and 3pi/4, there aren't any).
- in any arbitrary range range there may be several zeros.

Clearly what is needed is a (possibly empty) set of values.

So pseudocode of the function *really* asked for (not using Java as this is homework):

```
Set zeropoint(double a, double b)
{
    double middle = mid point of a and b;
    if a and be less than 0.0001 apart
    {
        if (sin(a) and sin(b) are on opposite sides of 0)
        { 
            return set containing middle
        }
        else
        {
            return empty set
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return union of zeropoint(a, middle) and zeropoint(middle, b)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a solution that doesn't require "some small limit"

Comment: @aepryus: "within some small limit" just means that you can't check for exactly zero because the nature of double means you'd be lucky to hit a point where sin(middle) is exactly 0.00000000000000.

Comment: @aepryus again:  Just realised what you meant.  Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, but there is a way around that.  Basically, one just wants to see if the function crosses the x axis within the interval, which doesn't require the tolerance check.

Comment: what does sin(a) and sin(b) are on opposite sides of 0 mean?

Comment: One is positive, the other is negative.  In that case you know you have found a zero.

Comment: and how do I realize return union of zeropoint(a, middle) and zeropoint(middle, b) as code? what does union mean?

Comment: The most elegant way of solving this problem would be to pass around a List that you can append your zeros to as you find them.  The final result then would be a List containing all the results.  However, for the purpose of this problem, I would just print the zeros as you find them and not return anything (i.e., return void).

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: It's the mathematical union of two sets.  In Java, if you are returning (say) Set<Double> it is the result of using the addAll(Set<<Double>) method. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: hm I do not understsand that, everything else is clear to me and I have implemented it. can you give an example please?

Comment: The exact Java would be `Set<Double> ret = zeropoint(a, middle); ret.addAll(zeropoint(middle, b); return ret`

Comment: how can you return double or 0 on the one side and then return a set?

Comment: You can't.  The function has to return a set, since there is a possibility of many or no zero points as I explained in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply saying "it gives me errors" is not very helpful. What kind of errors? Compile errors or uncaught exceptions at runtime?

For your code, two things stand out as possible problems:

1. the variable `mitte` does not appear to be declared anywhere.
2. you are using > and < to compare reals. While that is ok by itself, it is better to check for 0 using a tolerance instead of relying on < and >, to avoid problems due to floating point precision. For all practical purposes -0.000000000001 is 0.

There might be other problems as well, I just wrote down the ones that jumped out at first glance.

Edit:

Apparently the `mitte` was due to an error in pasting the code by the OP (and has since been corrected). As other answers have pointed out, the code falls in to infinite recursion. This is because the recursion calls are on the wrong intervals.

One thing to note, the sin function can be monotonically increasing for one choice of a and b, and monotonically decreasing at some other interval. e.g. It is increasing over [0,pi/2] and it is decreasing over [pi/2,3*pi/2]. Thus the recursive calls need to changed according to the original interval the search is being made in. For one interval Math.sin(middle)<0 implies that Math.sin(x)<0 for all x in [a,middle], but for some other interval the opposite is true. This probably why this falls into infinite recursion for the interval that you are trying. I think this works over some other interval where sin is actually decreasing. Try calling your function over [pi/2,3*pi/2].

Comment: I run this code from commandline, everything it says is "at Aufg3.nullstelle(Aufg3.java:18), this is repeated 1x times

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: Looks like a stack overflow exception is being thrown. This is most likely due to the fact that you've got the logic backwards (i.e. searching [a,middle] in place of [middle,b] and vice versa) as already pointed out by other answers. Your function never converges on an answer but falls into infinite recursion. I am actually surprised that it compiles at all. The variable `mitte` is never declared. Or did you correct that already and posted an older version of the code?

Comment: sorry, mitte should be middle to, in my code its all middle and not mitte

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are getting stack overflow errors at runtime.  The < and > signs are reversed.  Also, you should use .0001 and not 0 to compare to.

Edit 1:
Actually, your basic algorithm has issues.  What happens if there are more than one zero in the interval?  What happens if sin(a) and the sin(mitte) have the same sign?  What happens if there are no zeros in the interval?

Edit 2:
Ok, so I did the problem and fundamentally, your solution is problematic; I would try to start over in thinking how to solve it.

The major issue is that there could be multiple zeros in the interval and you are trying to find each of them.  Creating a function that returns a type double can only return one solution.  So, rather than creating a function to return double, just return void and print out the zeros as you find them.

Another hint: You are supposed to continue searching until a and b are within .0001 of each other.  Your final solution will not use .0001 in any other way.  (I.e, your check to see if you found a zero should not use the .0001 tolerance and nor will it use 0 exactly.  Think about how you will really know if you have found a zero when abs(a-b) is less than .0001.

Comment: I have to find just one zero point, so finding one the algorithm has to terminate

Comment: Well, technically, in your original post you say "I want to find the zero points".  But, aside from that given the wording and nature of the problem I suspect your professor wants you to be able to find all of the zeros.  JeremyP's solution above is very similar to the one I worked out and I strongly suspect is what the professor had in mind when he crafted the problem.  I would perhaps simplify it, by not bothering with the Set mechanics, but your final solution should be very similar.  At any rate, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the assignment to the end? It says:

> The search-interval[lower limit, upper
>   limit] should be halved until lower
>   limit and upper limit are less then
>   0.0001 away from each other.

So you can't expect `Math.sin(middle)` to return exactly zero because of floating point precision issues. Instead you need to stop the recursion when you reach 0.0001 precision.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're running into a `StackOverflowError`. This is due to the fact that you're never reaching a base case in your recursion. (`Math.sin(middle)` may never equal *exactly* 0!)

Your exercise says

> *[...] until lower limit and upper limit are less then 0.0001 away from each other.*

So, try putting this in top of your method:

```
double middle = (a + b)/2;
if (b - a < 0.0001)
    return middle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides some floating point problems other have mentioned, your algorithm seems to be based on the implicit assumptions that:

1. sin(a) is positive
2. sin(b) is negative, and
3. sin(x) is a decreasing function on the interval [a,b].

I see no basis for these assumptions.  When any of them is false I don't expect your algorithm to work.  They are all false when a=5 and b=8.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Math.sin(mitte) < 0){
```

Where is `mitte` declared? Isn't `mitte` `middle`?

Comment: This was almost certainly lost when the poster translated his variable names to english.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static double zeropoint(double a, double b){
    double middle = (a + b)/2;
    double result = middle;

    if (Math.abs(a - b) > 0.0001) {
        double sin = Math.sin(middle);
        if (Math.abs(sin) < 0.0001) {
           result = middle;
        } else if (sin > 0) {
           result = zeropoint(a, middle);
        } else {
           result = zeropoint(middle, b);
        }
    }
    return result;   
}
```

something like this i think - just to fix first errors

Comment: What if a = 0 and b = PI/2?  Then result is PI/4?

Comment: why do you think it is PI/4 ? sin(PI/4) is sqrt(2)/2, not zero

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking you were taking sin of a and b.

Comment: At any rate, what if there are multiple zeros in the interval?  I'm hesitant to give the correct solution since this is homework, but I suspect this solution will send him off in the wrong direction.

Comment: I tried with [5,8] it gives me 7,9999955 but I am sure that is not the zero point

Comment: Why do you have two stop conditions in the recursion? `abs(a-b)>0.0001` and `abs(sin) < 0.0001`? The second one does not conform to the assignment, "until lower limit and upper limit are less then 0.0001 away from each other". For example `zeropoint(-1.0,1.0);` would return right away, because `sin(middle) < 0.0001`. Please remove?

Comment: Fixed. With [5, 8] gives 6.2832. sin(6.2832) is 1.78E-5

Comment: @Ishtar, in your example zero is found, the program worked properly.

Comment: @Vladimir - 1) You program only works for zeropoint(a,-a); because of a flipped '>'. Try `-.1,.2` for example. 2) It does not do what it is supposed to do: "until lower limit and upper limit are less then 0.0001 away from each other." How dare you say it's even working?

Comment: @Ishtar 1) It works for (5,8). 2)returns -9.765625E-5 3) more than 0,0001. Can you please refresh the page, I have edited the source.

Comment: @Vladimir - Sorry, missed that edit. Point 1 is fixed indeed. Still `zeropoint(-.1,.2);` should return `1.220703125E-5`. Add `System.out.printf("a=%f b=%f a-b=%f\n",a,b,a-b);` to the top of the function. Last value should be <0.0001 according to "should be halved until lower limit and upper limit are less then 0.0001 away from each other". In your function `a-b` is greater than `0.0001`, it's `0.000586`, should continue till it's `0.000073`.

Comment: @Ishtar. Oh, it's just a question of approxi. One can increase accuracy by lowering this value in the condition.