# Return set of numbers in recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

following code searches for one zero point of a polynomial function. It uses recursion technique:

```
    private static double funktion(int[] koef, double x){
        return koef[0] * Math.pow(x,4) + koef[1] * Math.pow(x,3) + 
               koef[2] * Math.pow(x,2) + koef[3]*x + koef[4]; 
    }

    private static double nullstelle(double a, double b, int[] koef){
        double middle = (a + b)/2;
        double result = middle; 
        if(Math.abs(a-b) > 0.00001){
            double sin = funktion(koef, middle);
            if(sin == 0){
                result = middle;
            }else if(Math.signum(funktion(koef, a)) == 
                             Math.signum(funktion(koef, middle))){
                result = nullstelle(middle, b, koef);
            }else{
                result = nullstelle(a, middle, koef);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am wondering how to return all zero points. My ideas is to use an array but I am not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

I am not allowed to use anything else than arrays (e.g. hash tables or sets are not allowed)

Comment: does the array need to be sorted?

Comment: ok.  I provided the steps that will be of value to you below.

Comment: @Jeremy: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your solution as it stands suffers from one of the same problems as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086385/find-zero-points-with-recursion/4086845#4086845) in that you can't guarantee that you'll get the zero calculation exactly correct.  Unfortunately, this time you can't use the simple solution of checking that a and b have opposite signs because, for an arbitrary polynomial, a zero need not imply the function crosses the y = 0 line e.g. y = x^4.

Anyway, to answer your question:

1. create an array of size 4 of type `Double`.  Use null to denote that an array slot is empty.  As your function is a quartic, there is a maximum of four zeroes.
2. pass the array as a parameter in your function.
3. when you have detected a zero, fill in the first free slot left in the array with the value of the zero.

No actual Java provided because this is homework.

Comment: hm, so: double[] zeros = new double[3]? to save a double to one of this array slots do I have to use an index to specify the slot? I would do this in the if(sin == 0) statement...

Comment: Yes except `new Double[4]` as a quartic can have four zeros.

Comment: Index 0 1 2 3 would be 4 elements. in 3 you say fill in the first free slot. that means I have to address this slot by its index, I can not just do add(zero). so how do I do that`?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: That's why I said to use `Double` not `double`.  The reason you can't use 0 to denote a non value is that 0 might be one of the answers.  You need `array[freeSlot] = new Double(middle);`

Comment: I tested it but it isn't working. I added a System.out.println(result) after result = middle in the sin == 0 statement but it does not print anything more than -1.29....oO

Answer (score 2):

I would pass in a Collection such as a HashSet to your functions and put all the numbers you discover into it.

As you say you can only use arrays, then you know the maximum number of zero-points that can be found, presumably, so create an array of that size, assigned NaN to every element, then pass in that array and the maximum current index of it to every function call.  You will need to return the new size of the array as the result so that you always know how many numbers have been found.

Comment: I updated my question. I am not allowed to use anything else than arrays.

Comment: Ah, it's homework? You should in future tag the question as such to avoid answers suggesting a different API/library.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some explanation as this is homework:

1) We need to create an array of the data type you will be using to store zero points.  My guess is double.
2) The array will need some type of starting size, lets say `10` for the sake of discussion
3) In the `nullstelle` method we will add an element to the array created in `step 1`
4) If the array has size `LIMIT -1` we copy the array to a new array with size equal to `LIMIT * 2`
5) We now return this array.

If it needs to be sorted we can walk over the list utilizing whatever sort technique is to be decided on.

Answer (score 1):

Math.pow is a very expensive function. You can avoid it entirely using nested expressions. (And its shorter)

```
private static double funktion(int[] koef, double x){
     return (((koef[0] * x + koef[1]) * x + 
           koef[2]) * x + koef[3]) * x + koef[4]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public double[] returnOnlyZeros(int[] whatever1, double whatever2) {
  double[] result = new double[/*put the size here*/];

  // your math here

  // put the values into the result array

  return result;
 }
```

Comment: Pay attention to what @Woot4Moo said about resizing the array if you don't know the final size from start.